# Ionic serve --lab doesn't support pull to refresh

Tags: ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

when I use `ionic serve --lab`, the browser won't let me use the `pull-to-refresh gesture`.
When I click and drag my mouse the app doesn't react to it. I had it working this morning but then I shut down the `ionic serve` and after it it didn't work anymore. Code to the pull-to-refresh isn't changed.

When I use it on a device or emulator it does work.

Does anybody have a clue?
I'm testing on Chrome version 43.0.2357.124 m

Comment: What happens when you try this codepen, http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/mqolp?

Comment: Well... i tried the codepens and they were not working either. I restarted chrome and tried again but it didn't help. After rebooting it worked again, i dont understand why. This happened to me before... strange.